# Use of static classes to represent different forms of currency

Tags: java, static

I coded myself an issue last night while developing a small game.  The other day, I convinced myself that I should devote some of my spare time to something productive, so instead of gaming I decided I would start working on a text-based rpg.  I came, then, to the issue of representing currency in game.  Now, because this is just for fun, I'd like to challenge myself a bit.  Instead of just representing currency as a single value ( eg: a single type of coin called "gold piece" isn't the only kind of coin in the game .)

What I decided to do was create 4 types of coin - pence, copper, denar, and oren.  All 4 of the coins have values such as weight, volume, material, and name.  Furthermore, the coins have exchange rates, which determine their relative values.  The point of this was to permit different usages of what would otherwise be a boring old currency.  My issue is that I am unsure how to implement it.

What I arrived at last night was 4 classes ( Pence, Copper, Denar, Oren, ) extending an abstract class Coin.  Coin contains a lot of protected static elements, such as DENSITY, VOLUME, NAME, EXCHANGE for all 4 subclasses.

The constructors for the sub-classes look like this:

```
public Coppers() {
    super();
    super.metal = COPPER_METAL;
    super.name = COPPER;
    super.setVolume();
    super.setDensity();
    super.setWeight();
}
```

And the methods in the super class look like this:

```
protected void setDensity() {
    switch( getMetal()) {   
    case "copper":
        this.density = DENSITY_COPPER;
        break;
    case "silver":
        this.density = DENSITY_SILVER;
        break;
    case "gold":
        this.density = DENSITY_GOLD;
        break;
    default:
        this.density = DENSITY_COPPER;
        break;
    };
}
```

This seems terribly... wrong.  I'm not sure what the best practice would be.  I asked my friends about using a static class to hold these values, and received mixed responses.  The POINT of these classes though, is important.  Imagine the player class has an object called Purse, which keeps track of the number of different types of coins.  With their Purse, the player can exchange coins at banks, purchase goods, and sell goods for coins.  It wouldn't make any sense to hold a Set of all instantiated coins, right?  I just need the information, and the methods.  Does implementing a static class make sense, then?  How can I get all 4 coins working best, when they all share so many properties?

Comment: Look at [Java enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)s, which are basically static classes with some syntactic sugar.

Comment: Does density ever change? Why not set it with a setter for metal, same for weight and volume. Why protected? Wouldn't private be a better access modifier?

Comment: Is it important for a player which exact coins he has (so would having 100 cents make any situation different from having 1 dollar/euro)? If not, you can just have a simple `int purse` holding the total pennies, and only for the visual experience convert this number into oren, denar, copper and pennies.

Answer (score 1):

What you may do in this case is to use an `Enum`. You enumerate the constants you need, give them a type through their constructors.

Now that we have their type, we can compare it to the string you're handling within your code, if none of the types match, we set it to `Density.COPPER` by default.

```
Density density;

protected void setDensity (String metal) {
    for (Density d : Density.values()) {
        if (metal.equals(d.getType())) {
            this.density = d;
            return;
        }
    }
    this.density = Density.COPPER;
}

enum Density {
    COPPER("copper"),
    SILVER("silver"),
    GOLD("gold");

    String type;

    Density(String s) {
        type = s;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's work backwards here.

> Imagine the player class has an object called Purse, which keeps track of the number of different types of coins. With their Purse, the player can exchange coins at banks, purchase goods, and sell goods for coins.

What this implies:

```
public class Purse {
    private final List<Coin> coins = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**This tells me that enums are not sufficient (enough) here.**  An enum in this context describes multiple states; what you're looking for are actual objects which can hold values that you need to do some calculations on.

If our intention is to hold on to this currency, I don't see anything wrong with *some* central object to describe it.

In my mind, using an abstract class for this is probably fine, but you're missing a critical component:  a factory to create the type of coin you want.  You'll also want to reduce the responsibilities of the coin altogether - it's fine for a coin to know its value, but it shouldn't care what its value is relative to other coins; that's the responsibility of some kind of exchange object which intends to produce a number of coins based on the value of your given coin.

---

So let's write the constructor for the abstract class.  If we're thinking of creating a generic coin, we need to know its volume, density, and weight.  The name is provided by virtue of its class name, so you really shouldn't need to worry about that; you can extract it later.

If you want some sort of coin hierarchy, you can leverage `Comparable`; state the ordering there instead of through enumeration.

```
public abstract class Coin implements Comparable<Coin> {

    protected final int volume;
    protected final int density;
    protected final int weight;

    public Coin(int volume, int density, int weight) {
        this.volume = volume;
        this.density = density;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public int getDensity() {
        return density;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

This describes the barebones `Coin` type.

For an example, let's describe the `Copper` type here as well.  This code makes the assumption that coin of the same type is comparable otherwise it demotes itself (with Copper being at the bottom of the list).

Observe a few things:

- We preserve a lot of the original logic from the parent class
- We override `compareTo` (because we must), and we let that drive the chief way of ordering on coins.
- This does *not* describe any sort of conversion since the coins really shouldn't need to know about that.  They have no value between coins until it's time to actually convert them.  Think [foreign exchange.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_market)

```
public class Copper extends Coin {

    public Copper(final int volume, final int density, final int weight) {
        super(volume, density, weight);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Coin otherCoin) {
        if(otherCoin instanceof Copper) {
            return (volume - getVolume()) + (density - getDensity()) + (weight - getWeight());
        }
        // assume Coppers are worth the least
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```

The other currencies are left as an exercise for the reader.

The last thing I want to cover is some form of generator for all of your currencies.  This is where a bit of reflection magic can really help to invoke the constructor you care about.

I've also made this return an `Optional<T extends Coin>` so that, in the event the generation *fails* for some reason, you have an optional to work with instead of `null`.

```
public class CoinFactory {

    private CoinFactory() {

    }

    public static <T extends Coin> Optional<T> generateCoin(int weight, int volume, int density, Class<T> clazz) {
        Optional<T> coin = Optional.empty();
        try {
            coin = Optional.of(clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, int.class, int.class)
                 .newInstance(weight, volume, density));
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return coin;
    }

}
```

You can use this `main` method to smoke test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Optional<Copper> x = CoinFactory.generateCoin(10, 20, 30, Copper.class);
    if(x.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(x.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on making coin an interface opposed to abstract class? And on an unrelated note, would making a 'unit' metric that all coins need to be able to convert to / create from be good? How about keeping enums for the coin types like `TimeUnit` and keeping counts for each type. As in: in purse class `EnumMap<Coin, Integer> coins;`

Comment: What a fantastic answer.  I appreciate the effort to help me realize this.  I think, first, I will read up on Enums and try to integrate them into the implementation.  I would like to clarify something - I really do not think that an ArrayList of coins in a Purse object makes sense.  I think I would prefer that interactions involving currency be handled by an external class, and coins should be kept track of by simple arithmetic operations.  The static values ( or maybe enums? ) would serve to determine the semantics of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Put a private `Map` in `Coin` for Density, with keys being "copper", "gold", and "silver", and the values being the `DENSITY_` constants.  `setDensity()` should simply run:

```
this.density = densityMap.get(getMetal());
```

Or better yet, scrap `setDensity()`, and instead simply have `getDensity()`, which returns `densityMap.get(getMetal())`.

Comment: I was wrong; an Enum is the better solution, though I stand by the idea that having setDensity is probably an unnecessary setup step.

Answer (score 0):

Since the four kinds of coin don’t differ in behavior, one class is enough. I suggest this:

```
public enum Coin {
  PENCE, COPPER, DENAR, OREN;

  private static final String[] METAL = { "copper", "copper", "silver", "gold" };
  private static final int[] VALUE = { 1, 12, 60, 360 };

  public String getMetal() {
    return METAL[ordinal()];
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return VALUE[ordinal()];
  }
}
```

Comment: Enums were something I had been thinking about using all day.  I think I'll whip something up and report back.

Comment: Agree, most of the answers are unnecessarily complicated for this simple task.